# Opening project with Terminal resets its configuration

Tags: visual-studio-code, konsole

I was using `Tilix` terminal and its all fine.
But when I try to use `Konsole` whenever I try to open a project with:

```
code .
or
code /my-project
```

it opens *asking if I trust the Authors* (everytime, doesnt matter if I click **YES**).
and resets my theme/icons/font-family/sizes/ everything...

How can this be?
Works perfectly with one Terminal but resets everything with the other.